# MySQL Fetch Array Each Row Function

Tags: php, html, sql, database

This is the first time I'm using this website, I have recently started working on a project where the webpage will display two table, one of the table will gather all the information from a SQL Database and place them in the table along with a button next to each rows allowing you to insert that record to another to the other table, so far, this is the code I have written:

```
//Include the Following Files
include 'connect.php';

//Select All Price Plans
$query = "SELECT * FROM pricing";
$result = mysql_query($query);

//Print all Plans in Table 
while ($pricing = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    echo "<table border=1>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" .$pricing['planID'].  "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$pricing['planTitle']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$pricing['planDescription']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$pricing['planPricing']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . **<a href="'. $link .'">BUTTON HERE</a>** . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<table>";
}  


//Assign $link to Case     
$link = '?run=planA'; 

//Pre-defined Functions
function planA()
{ 
$query = "INSERT into restaurant_plan (`planID`, `planTitle`, `planDescription`, `planPricing`) SELECT * FROM pricing WHERE planID='2' ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
} 

//Setting Case to Run Each Functions
if (isset($_GET['run'])) $linkchoice=$_GET['run']; 
else $linkchoice=''; 

switch($linkchoice)
{       
    case 'planA': 
    planA(); 
    break; 

    case 'planB': 
    planB(); 
    break;              
}
```

Could anyone suggest any guide or possibly an example how I could assign a *function to each rows*? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: What, exactly, isn't working?

Comment: How are you connecting to the db?

Comment: Well, this is the script I have so far, but I'm confused how I can get it to assign a function based on each rows, I did try a counter but that didn't worked out. Thanks

Comment: I agree with @Matt, please state your problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "assign a function" ?

Comment: Well, the script will gather all the records from the database and what I actually wanted is to have a button next to the record which allow that row to be added into another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code prints one table for each record in table "pricing", use this code instead :

```
//Select All Price Plans
$mysqli = new mysqli("hostname", "username", "pass", "dbname");

$query = "SELECT * FROM pricing";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);

//Print all Plans in Table    

echo "Available Price Plans";          
echo "<table border=1>";
while ( $pricing = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" .$pricing['planID'].  "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$pricing['planTitle']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$pricing['planDescription']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$pricing['planPricing']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .'<a href="'. $link .'"><img style="border:none;" src="'. $icon .'" /></a>'. "</td>";
    //print a button as you mentioned
    echo "<td>"."<form action='#' method='get'><input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$pricing['planID']."'/><input type='submit' value='copy'/></form></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

and your function :

```
function planA()
{ 
    // get selected plan info
    $query = "SELECT * FROM pricing";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    $row = $res->fetch_assoc();

    //copy info to table 'restaurant_plan'
    $query = "INSERT into restaurant_plan (".$_GET["id"].", ".$row["planTitle"].", ".$row["planDescription"].", ".$row["planPricing"].")";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but if you want your code to be cleaner & more readable/maintainable, you should use HTML with PHP inserted, rather than echoing HTML via PHP:

```
<?php
//Select All Price Plans
$query = "SELECT * FROM pricing";
$result = mysql_query($query);

//Print all Plans in Table     
?>
Available Price Plans
<?php while ($pricing = mysql_fetch_array($result)) : ?>
    <table border=1>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $pricing['planID'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $pricing['planTitle'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $pricing['planDescription'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $pricing['planPricing'] ?></td>
            <td><a href="<?= $link ?>"><img style="border:none;" src="<?= $icon ?>" /></a></td>
        </tr>
    <table>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Also, as I mentioned in the comments above, you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Answer (score 0):

Change your table output to the following:

> ```
> <table border="1">
> <?php
> while ($pricing = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
> ?>
>        <tr>
>        <td><?php echo $pricing['planID']; ?></td>
>        <td><?php echo $pricing['planTitle']; ?></td>
>        <td><?php echo $pricing['planDescription']; ?></td>
>        <td><?php echo $pricing['planPricing']; ?></td>
>        <td><a href='<?php echo $link; ?>'><img style="border:none;" src='<?php echo $icon; ?>' /></a></td> 
>        </tr>
>    <?php     
>    }  
>    ?>
> <table>
> ```

Double check you database connection as well to ensure data can be retrieved.